# How do I find a next element and add a class to it?

Tags: jquery

I am building a form where you can added persons by clicking on the plus and delete them by clicking on minus(obviously)

I have a screenshot to create a better view for you:
[image]

If I press I would like to delete Name person2 and E-mail person 2 I have writin something like this:

```
 $('.fa-minus-circle').click( function() {
    $(this).parents('.form-input-wrap').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).closest('.form-input-wrap', 'div').addClass('test');
});
```

It is working for the `parent` and it hides it but how do i access the next `.form-input-wrap` to `addClass('hidden')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method like following.

```
$(this).closest('.form-input-wrap').next('.form-input-wrap').addClass('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function on your parent form-input-wrap :).

```
$('.fa-minus-circle').click( function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('.form-input-wrap:first');
    $parent.removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
    $parent.next('.form-input-wrap', 'div').addClass('test');
});
```